# Coherence in compresive sensing

Tags: compressive-sensing, linear-algebra

I am starting to write my master thesis, and it's in field of compressive sensing. I have some problems with math behind it. I don't understand the concept of matrix coherence. I know how it is calculated and definitions but what does it mean for my transform matrix? Can someone explain the coherence of matrix to me, in simple terms?

Comment: "Matrix coherence" usually means how much the singular vectors of a matrix correlate to standard basis. I can see how that might be very relevant to compressive sensing. Can you maybe give us a few of the references to what you've read to get the notation/definition? It's definitely easier to explain math when the math looks the same as what the person asking is used to.

Comment: I am reading book by Ljubisa Stankovic called Digital signal processing. There is a chapter for spare signal processing.

Comment: Are you talking about mutual coherence?

Comment: Yes, mutual coherence. I know that it's measure of cross-correlation between columns of my measurement matrix. But my question is why does matrix need to be incoherent for compressed sensing. Why is it important?